# Kernel panic - not syncing: Requested init /linuxrc failed (error -2)

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, u-boot, imx6

I build an embedded linux with YOCTO for the KARO TX6S-8035 target. I use the 
Mfgtools-TX6-2018-01 tool to flash images into the board but when i boot the device i have the following error:  **Kernel panic - not syncing: Requested init /linuxrc failed (error -2)**.
How can i fix this?

Here is the result of printenv from U-BOOT:
[printenv](https://pastebin.com/7jvaM0wV)

`And the serial output from the board:` [serial output](https://pastebin.com/amumfBvJ)

Answer (score 2):

**Kernel panic - not syncing: Requested init /linuxrc failed (error -2)**

In my case, I create initrd with busybox. /linuxrc execute error, because of it can't find the dynamic library.

execute below script after mount the initrd

```
file linuxrc
```

- linuxrc: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter **/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1**, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, stripped

**Fix-Option1:**

copy library to initrd.

```
mkdir -p $WORKSPACE/initrd
mount $WORKSPACE/ramdisk.img $WORKSPACE/initrd -t ext2 -o loop=/dev/loop0
pushd $WORKSPACE/initrd/
cp -rf /opt/buildtools/gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/libc/lib ./
cp -rf /opt/buildtools/gcc-arm-10.2-2020.11-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/libc/lib64 ./
aarch64-none-linux-gnu-strip $WORKSPACE/initrd/lib/*
aarch64-none-linux-gnu-strip $WORKSPACE/initrd/lib64/*
aarch64-none-linux-gnu-strip $WORKSPACE/initrd/bin/busybox
popd

umount $WORKSPACE/initrd
gzip -9 $WORKSPACE/ramdisk.img
```

**Fix-Option2:**

build busybox statically.

```
make -j16 -C $WORKSPACE/$BUSYBOX ARCH="arm64" LDFLAGS="--static" CROSS_COMPILE="aarch64-none-linux-gnu-" install
```

- busybox-1.32.1/_install/bin/busybox: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), **statically linked**, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, stripped

Comment: In Option2, you can also make sure `CONFIG_STATIC=y` in .config file, then make again.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel is looking for the init program and cannot find it. Most likely your image is corrupt. More info here: [What is linuxrc purpose and is it needed in the rootfs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45268712/what-is-linuxrc-purpose-and-is-it-needed-in-the-rootfs)

I would try:

1. reflash the image
2. check the image to be sure that linuxrc exists
3. post a questions to the [meta-freescale mailing list](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/listinfo/meta-freescale)

Also, I do not know what setup you are using, but I would look at the [FSL Community BSP](http://freescale.github.io/). There is a good chance others are building for that platform.

Comment: I add "init=sbin/init" into u-boot environment.